# how to pass the search keyword for a url using Angular js and how to retrive results based on that search keyword

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-material

I want to display search results using angular js, when we select from auto suggestion, the search keyword passing though the url and display the specific search keyword results. Iam new to using angular js can somebody help it.

js file

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q, GetCountryService) {

        $scope.searchText = "";
        $scope.Person = [];
        $scope.selectedItem = [];
        $scope.isDisabled = false;
        $scope.noCache = false;

        $scope.selectedItemChange = function (item) {
            //alert("Item Changed");
        }
        $scope.searchTextChange = function (str) {
            return GetCountryService.getCountry(str);
        }

    });

    app.factory('GetCountryService', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            getCountry: function(str) {
                // the $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service
                // so it returns a promise for us by default
                var url = "http://www.example/index.php/admin/default/searchcompanies?token="+str;
                return $http.get(url)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (typeof response.data.records === 'object') {
                           alert(response.data.records);
                            return response.data.records;
                        } else {
                            // invalid response
                            return $q.reject(response.data.records);
                        }

                    }, function(response) {
                        // something went wrong
                        return $q.reject(response.data.records);
                    });
            }
        };
    });
```

View file

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex="85" flex-xs="100" layout="row" layout-align="left center">
      <form name="searchForm" flex ng-controller="myCtrl" layout="row" ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
        <div md-no-float class="md-block m-0 md-accent md-subhead" flex="50" flex-xs="70">
          <md-content>
            <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="isDisabled" md-no-cache="noCache" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in searchTextChange(searchText)" md-item-text="item.title" md-min-length="0" placeholder="Select Company?">
              <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.title}}</span>
              </md-item-template>
              <md-not-found>
                No Company matching "{{searchText}}" were found.
              </md-not-found>
            </md-autocomplete>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-accent m-0" style="display:inline-block;" onclick="location.href='/index.php/admin/default/searchresults?={{item.title}}';">
              <md-icon ng-bind="'search'"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </md-content>
          <br/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yoiu want the way to trigger `selectedItemChange` right ?

Comment: yes, that keyword passed to the url @JulienTASSIN